# Android: overlay app that can grab text from the underlay app?

Tags: android, android-studio

Is it possible to have an app overlay on another app and be able to grab text from it. If I had a browser opened and have an app that can grab text from the website  and placed into text to speech, is this possible or is there something similar to this?

Comment: Google NOW has this functionality

Comment: I guess Google NOW uses image processing for this purpose

Answer (score 0):

TalkBack is an app which uses android accessibility services to read out the text underneath when a user touches it. So you can also make your own accessibility service.